# Mocking Dictionary in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I'm new to patching/mocking in general and in python in particular. I am trying to patch a dict which will be accessed in a test case using the following

```
obj = Foo(None)
with patch.dict(obj.bar.items_dict,{TEST_DIR + '/Transparent.gif', data}):
    output = obj.create_css_for_imgs()
```

But i get the following error. Please understand that the `__init__()` function of Foo makes bar `None` by default

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items_dict'

The classes are as follows:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, barVal):
        self.bar = barVal

class Bar():
    def __init__(self, val)
        self.items_dict = {}
        self._load(val)
```

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question.

Comment: I actually want to know how I should go about it, I guessed it's because bar is initialized to `None` but then in my real code it's setup somewhere else before this function... here I just need to patch bar.items_dict

Comment: @KennyOstrom can you explain how I can do this?

Comment: @tsar2512 Could you show your `Foo` class, imports and full test?

Comment: mock the bar object, instead of letting it run with None. You can't set properties on None.

Comment: @KennyOstrom so that's what I want to understand how do I mock the object... i.e. the only attributes in the bar object I am concerned about is items_dict..

Comment: @DanilaGanchar updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that you need `patch` in your case. `Patch` more ofen uses to 'mocking' functions of modules. You can use `Mock` object to create a structure for testing(with 'mocked' methods and properties).

> First of all, I think you got the error because you sent `None` to
>   constructor. But `NoneType` doesn't have `items_dict` property.

Here a small example which can help you:

```
from mock import Mock

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, bar_val):  # type: (Bar) -> None
        self.bar = bar_val

    def get_bar_items_dict(self):  # type: () -> dict
        # just example - return items_dict of Bar object
        return self.bar.items_dict

    def create_css_for_imgs(self):  # type: () -> str
        return 'example'


class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.items_dict = {}
        # other properties...


class TestExample(TestCase):

    def test_create_css_for_imgs(self):
        # create Mock instead Bar object and say that items_dict isn't empty dict
        bar = Mock(items_dict={'custom': 'dict'})
        # foo.bar will be 'Mock' object
        foo = Foo(bar)
        # check result of 'create_css_for_imgs' Foo object
        self.assertEqual(
            foo.create_css_for_imgs(),
            'example'
        )

        # check result of foo.bar.items_dict
        self.assertDictEqual(
            foo.get_bar_items_dict(),
            {'custom': 'dict'}
        )
```

**So let's summarize.** You got the error because you tried to get `items_dict` of `None` type(looks like: `a = None a.items_dict`).
You can create any object for testing(with 'mocked' methods and properties) without 'patching' of original class. Example:

```
one = Mock(one_propery=1)
two = Mock(one=one)
three = Mock(two=two)
three.my_method.return_value = [1, 2, 3]
# check our object
print three.two.one.one_propery # 1
print three.my_method() # [1, 2, 3]
```

In some cases we need to 'mock' method of class(for example for group tests). In this case you can use `patch`:

```
    mocked_create = mock.patch(
        'your_pack.your_module.Foo.create_css_for_imgs',
        return_value='changed example'
    )
    # change 'example' to 'changed example'
    mocked_create.start()
    foo = Foo(Bar())
    print foo.create_css_for_imgs()  # 'changed example'
    mocked_create.stop()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you this is pretty detailed and gives me a good explanation of how mock vs patch works.... I already fixed my code to use Mock and it worked but this helps anyways :)

Comment: @tsar2512 I was glad to help. Good luck ;)